# Complex latex document: how to locate offending package dependency [solved: was using dirty build]

Tags: errors, input, include, pdfpages, logging

For final distribution, certain appendix includes the `pdfpages` package. However, appendices should be skipped for normal "draft" versions, or while working on individual chapters.

I am having problems figuring out which file is referring a particular `pdfpages` counter in these draft versions. Not including the pdfpages package in the preamble results in the following error: (once per chapter), even though there are no uncommented references to any `\includepdf`* commands` (in desperation, I have commented out the ones in the not-to-be-compiled appendixes)

```
! LaTeX Error: No counter 'AM@survey' defined.
```

How would you find out the source of this error? After grepping the files repeatedly, I can find no reference to the package.

**Solved**

The Makefile included with the style package did not recurse into subdirectories to remove outdated files when invoking target 'clean'. After fixing this, everything works as expected. Notifying maintainer, and flogging myself for not noticing earlier.

Comment: look in the log each time tex opens a file it shows `(` and the file path, once it stops reading the file it outputs `)` so by matching `()` you can see which file is being processed, that's the classic way, these days there is also `-file-line-error` command line argument which makes it show file name as well as line number in error messages

Comment: Perhaps unrelated but... Remember to delete all aux files before compiling again when removing/adding packages.

Comment: Thanks JLDiaz - always using "make clean pdflatex" just in case. @David Carlisle, see comment to tohecz's answer: I still can't find the culprit...

Comment: You mention you have separate files for each chapter. Also one `.aux` per chapter. This suggests that you use `\include` for the chapters in the main file. Try changing those for `\input`.

Comment: This is complicated to carry out, as the \includes are being moderated by an `\includeonly`, which is the one that actually receives the list of files to compile... it is a rather involved styling package widely used around my institution.

Answer (score 2):

Each file when read on input is enclosed in parentheses, starting with the file name. Parentheses should be used for no other purpose in the log file so it should be possible to track the behaviour. For example, this is a part of one log file:

```
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2005/09/16 v1.4f Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
```

It shows that the message `Document Class ...` is printed during the reading of the file `article.cls`, and that the file `size10.clo` is input from `article.cls` as well.

Comment: The error seems to be embedded into each chapter's .aux file, with no indication of which style or header included which lines within the .aux. There is a large block of \setcounter at the top of each these .aux files; and one of these counters (AM@survey) only works if the pdfpages package was included in the preamble, even though there is no mention of includepdf anywhere in the files being compiled (!!).

Comment: Remove all these `aux` files and do a fresh clean compilation. That should solve your issue.

Comment: checked the supplied Makefile; it turns out the .aux removal was not recursive. Sorry for wasting your time, and thanks for pointing me to the problem.